# Why the pointer hack for finding the size of an array in C giving different value when used in a called function

Tags: c, arrays, function

This is the code below to illustrate the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int arr[]);

int main() {
    int arr[10];
    int n = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    func(arr);
    return 0;
}

void func(int arr[]) {
    int n = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Output of the above code is:

```
10
268435906
```

Comment: `int n=*(&arr+1)-arr;`..are you sure?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No that's correct (in that it will most likely work even though it's technically invalid). `&arr + 1` is a pointer to an array, dereference it (i.e. `*(&arr + 1)`) and you get an array, which then decays to a pointer to its first element (which will be pointing to one element beyond the end of `arr`, i.e. effectively a pointer to `arr[10]`).

Comment: @JensGustedt: this question is not an exact duplicate, it uses a different expression to compute the array size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the syntax used for its definition `void func(int arr[])`, function `func` receives a pointer to the first element of the array. The definition is clearer as `void func(int *arr)`.

The expression `*(&arr+1)-arr` evaluates at compile time to the number of elements of an array **only** if `arr` is defined as an array. If `arr` is a pointer, it dereferences memory after the pointer and subtracts the pointer value, which is meaningless and in most circumstances has undefined behavior.

A more common (and more readable) expression to get the number of element of an array is

```
n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

If `arr` is an array, dividing its size in bytes by the size of an element in bytes produces the number of elements. The expression is evaluated at compile time, no runtime overhead. If `arr` is a pointer, dividing its size by the size of the type it points to is defined, but useless, just like your expression.

Answer (score 5):

When declaring an array argument in a function, it's not an array at all, instead it's a *pointer*.

The declaration

```
void funct(int arr[]);
```

is actually equal to

```
void funct(int *arr);
```

And that's the difference between the results you see. In the `main` function `&arr` is a pointer to the array, but in `func` the expression `&arr` is a pointer to the *pointer variable*. Those two pointers are very different.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever arrays are passed as the arguments to functions, they will decay into pointers in the function parameters.

[C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) :

> Since **arrays decay immediately into pointers**, an array is never
>   actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function
>   receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the
>   corresponding parameter as an array:
>
> void f(char a[]) { ... }

The name of the array `arr` is decayed into the pointer to the first element of the array by the compiler. As a result, dereferencing the pointer yields the value stored at the first location of an array.